# Retain cycle with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, retain-cycle

I'm writing a gallery with images which can be loaded by url with `AFNetworking`.

In `Init` method of the `ImageView` object I call a function that send a request. Here:

```
- (void) loadWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:TimeOut];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setHTTPShouldUsePipelining:YES];

    __weak AOWImageView *safeSelf = self;

    m_operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                       imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                                    success:^
                   (NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
                   {
                       [safeSelf setImage:image];
                   }
                                                                    failure:^
                   (NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                   {
                       [safeSelf setNoImageLabelOpaque];
                   }];

    [m_operation start];
}
```

If the `ImageView` is outside the visible part of the screen `- (void) dealloc` is called. I cancel operation loading image in this method so: `[m_operation cancel];`. I guess that the operations are not canceled because the memory is increasing and isn't released.

[image]

I think that there is retain cycle. I want to understand how to write it right. Thanks.

Comment: Is `m_operation` a property on this class, then?

Comment: This is private field of `ImageView`. `AFImageRequestOperation *m_operation;`

Comment: How much memory do you appear to be leaking? A few kilobytes or several MB?

Comment: The memory is increased by the size of image. ie several MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a retain cycle in the code snippet you posted, so if you are leaking memory, it may be due to another part of your app's code...

Regarding "best practices" for `AFNetworking` and loading images-

`AFNetworking`  has a built in category on `UIImageView` that has convenience methods for setting an an image view's image via a URL.

See `UIImageView+AFNetworking`, specifically `setImageWithURL:` method and related. This also has the advantage of keeping a cache (so you don't have to fetch images again if requested multiple times), which AFAIK, doesn't appear to done by `AFImageRequestOperation`.

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried to use the category but there is no effect. Now UIImage objects with little memory size is living and isn't released. I will find in another part of code.